# Bullet list in tikz environment

Tags: lists, tikz-styles, bullets

I am working with **tikz** environment for making a figure with the following features.

**1)** A rounded rectangle with a figure headline

**2)** Partitioned into two, with sub-headlines

**3)** In each part a few small rounded boxes with text. all boxes are the same in single side. but rectangles of the left side is smaller than rectangles of the right side( need two styles, I made only one style, and I don't know how to make two styles in a figure)

**4)** After boxes, big curly braces are needed(that covers all boxes) and next to the curly braces, need a bullet list in both side(while I made this bullet list, so many errors are coming, so I removed this part from code).

**5)** Boxes of the left side need to be right-aligned and right side boxes need to be left-aligned (in my work both are centre aligned if we make two separate styles for each box it may simple).

**6)** Bullet list need to be diamond-shaped. And left side curly brace is a closing bracket, and the bullet list is right to this. Right side curly brace is opening bracket type and bullet list left to this. Both bullet lists are left-aligned.

Thanks in advance.

```
\usepackage{graphicx, sectsty, etoolbox}%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.25cm, twocolumn}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}



\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
%\usepackage{authblk}

\title{A figure document}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section: tikzpicture}
\lipsum[2-5]
\begin{figure}[b]
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            myrectangle/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=65, minimum height=3, rounded corners=2, blue, text=black ,  text align=left, fill=blue!5}
        ]
   \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=268, minimum height=140, rounded corners=5, blue, thick, text height= -15cm] at (0,0);

    \node [blue, thick] at (0,2.1){\scriptsize Head line of the figure};% figure head
    \node [red, thick] at (-2.7,1.25){\scriptsize Sub head1};% sub head
    %curly brackets
   \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt]
(-2.3,-1.7) -- (-2.3,1.05) node [black,midway] ;
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(2.3,-2.4) -- (2.3,1) node [black,midway];
    \node [red, thick] at (1.7,1.25){\scriptsize  Sub head2};


% need a diamond-shaped bullet list 


   \draw [blue, thick] (-4.7,1.7) -- (4.7,1.7);
   \draw [blue, thick] (-1.2,1.7) -- (-1.2,-2.5);
   %------------------------------left side box
            \node[myrectangle] (a) at (-3.3,.80) {\scriptsize text1};
            \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of a] (b) {\scriptsize  text2};
            \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of b] (c) {\scriptsize  text3};
             \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of c] (d) {\scriptsize  text4};
             \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of d] (e) {\scriptsize  text5};
            \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of e] (f) {\scriptsize  text6};

    %------------------------------ right side box
    \node[myrectangle] (a) at (3.3,.8) {\scriptsize text7};
        \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of a] (b) {\scriptsize  text8};
        \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of b] (c) {\scriptsize  text9};
        \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of c] (d) {\scriptsize  text10};
        \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of d] (e) {\scriptsize  text11};
        \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of e] (f) {\scriptsize  text12};

        \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of f] (g) {\scriptsize  text13};
        \node[myrectangle, below=0.02 of g] (h) {\scriptsize  text14};

\end{tikzpicture}  
 \caption{A figure containing two types of data}
    \label{EHR}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: To make two styles, define two different styles ... You have `myrectangle/.style={..}`. Add e.g. `myrectangle2/.style={...}`, and use `myrectangle2` for one set of nodes, `myrectangle` for the other. There are also a couple of errors in your diagram (missing node texts for a few nodes, and `text align` should be just `align`). Regarding the list, do you mean the text in the list should form a diamond shape? Or that the lists are within a diamond?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for your help. I need a normal list without any outer boundary. instead of normal round-shaped bullet points, I need diamond-shaped bullet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below shows one possibility of doing this. There are some comments in the code, please ask if there is any part of it that needs further explanation.

[image: output of the code below]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
% for \blacklozenge
\usepackage{amssymb}

% the enumitem package is used for customizing lists
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{
   fit,
   positioning,
   chains,
   decorations.pathreplacing
}

% define a new list type based on itemize
\newlist{diagramlist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[diagramlist,1]{%
   nosep, % reduce whitespace in list
   label=$\blacklozenge$, % set the type of bullet point
   left=0pt % reduce the space on the left side
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   % this defines the gap between the small boxes
   node distance=0.2mm,
   % this defines the width of the box containing the lists
   declare function={listW=2cm;},
   % common styles for the two rectangle types
   baserect/.style={ 
      draw,
      rounded corners=2,
      blue,
      text=black,
      fill=blue!5,
      font=\scriptsize
    },
   % make styles for left and right rectangles, with 
   % different text widths and alignments, based on the baserect style defined above
   % change the text widths to whatever to find appropriate
   leftrect/.style={baserect, text width=3cm, align=right},
   rightrect/.style={baserect, text width=4cm, align=left},
   % make a style for the nodes containing the lists
   listnode/.style={
      midway,
      text width=listW,
      font=\scriptsize
   },
   % make a style for the nodes containing the titles
   titlenode/.style={
      red,
      font=\scriptsize,
      above=1.5mm
      }
]

% local bounding box=left will make node called left which fits
% around the content in the scope environment
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=left]

% a chain is a way of automatically placing nodes
% "l going below" means the chain is called l and runs downward
\begin{scope}[
   start chain=l going below,
   every node/.append style={leftrect, on chain}
   ]
  \node {text 1};
  \node {text 2};
  \node {text 3};
  \node {text 4};
  \node {text 5};
  \node {text 6};
\end{scope}

% then draw the brace. the first and last node in the chain are automatically
% named l-begin and l-end
\draw [
  decorate,
  decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=4pt}
  ] 
    (l-begin.north east) -- (l-end.south east)
    node[listnode, right=15pt] (leftlist) {%
      \begin{diagramlist}
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
      \end{diagramlist}
      };
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=right]
\begin{scope}[
   start chain=r going below,
   every node/.append style={rightrect, on chain}
   ]
   % place first node at the same height as the first node in the left part
   % at a distance right of the node for the left list
   % the distance is 1cm more than the text width of the list nodes
  \node [right=listW + 1cm of l-1.east-|leftlist.east] {text 1};
  \node {text 2};
  \node {text 3};
  \node {text 4};
  \node {text 5};
  \node {text 6};
  \node {text 7};
  \node {text 8};
\end{scope}

\draw [
   decorate,
   decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=4pt}
   ]
    (r-begin.north west) -- (r-end.south west)
    node[listnode, left=15pt] (rightlist) {%
      \begin{diagramlist}
        \item foo2
        \item bar2
        \item baz2
      \end{diagramlist}
      };
\end{scope}

% titles for subparts
\node [titlenode] (sub1) at (left.north) {Sub head 1};
\node [titlenode] (sub2) at (right.north) {Sub head 2};

% title for the whole thing
\node [titlenode, blue, inner ysep=2mm] (head) at (current bounding box.north) {Headline of figure};

% use the fit library to draw the frame around the whole thing
\node [baserect, fill=none, fit=(current bounding box)] (frame) {};

% first define a coordinate midway between the two list nodes
\path (leftlist.east) -- coordinate (mid) (leftlist.east -| rightlist.west);

% then draw the dividers
\draw [blue] (frame.west |- head.south) -- (frame.east |- head.south);
\draw [blue] (mid |- frame.south) -- (mid |- head.south);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a question: Why did you need to use ```scope'''? When drawing the braces and writing out the list of foo/bar/baz etc., why couldn't a node by itself work?

Comment: @lazulikid In this case the inner `scope` is needed because I used a `chain` to position the nodes. Of course you don't need to use a `chain`, but it's convenient. The outer scope isn't strictly needed  at all, it's just used to define the `local bounding box` nodes, which in turn are used to position the "subtitles". I could have placed those titles with  e.g. `\path (l-1.west|-leftlist.east) -- coordinate (m) (leftlist.east) (m|-l-1.north) node [titlenode] {Sub head 1};` though.

Comment: I see, so in general does one use scope when trying to club a bunch of different elements together? Like could I have a scope with a matrix, a tikzpicture, and a list? (just some random tex elements that come to mind)

Comment: @lazulikid A `scope` always goes inside a `tikzpicture`, not the other way around. It is defined by TikZ, for use in `tikzpicture`s. A typical use might be if you have many diagram elements that you want to use same style for. I did that here, you can see that I have `every node/.append style={...}` in the options to the `scope`, meaning that I don't have to specify the same style for every single node in the `scope`. Another typical use might be `\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm] ... \end{scope}` which will shift all the elements in the `scope` 2cm to the right.